# Windows 8: Download string with encoding (WinRT)

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

I use this code to download string from the Internet

```
public static async Task<string> DownloadPageAsync(string url)
{
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler {UseDefaultCredentials = true, AllowAutoRedirect = true};
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);            
    client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 196608;
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

     string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     return responseBody;
  }
```

but it only works for UTF8 documents. Where do I set the Encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WinRT the HttpContent reads Enconding from the Headers property. If the HTTP response from server doesn't set the Content-Type header with encoding, it tries to find BOM mark in the stream and if there's no BOM it will default to the UTF-8 encoding.

If the server is not sending the right Content-Type header you use the HttpContent.ReadAsStreamAsync() method and use your own instance of the Encoding class to correctly decode data.

Comment: solved it using a custom generated encoding class according to http://www.hardcodet.net/2010/03/silverlight-text-encoding-class-generator

Answer (score 2):

Change ReadAsStringAsync to ReadAsBufferAsync and parse result with required encoding

```
var buffer = await response.Content.ReadAsBufferAsync();
byte [] rawBytes = new byte[buffer.Length];
using (var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer))
{
    reader.ReadBytes(rawBytes);
}

var res = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rawBytes, 0, rawBytes.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the "ContentEncoding" property of your HttpResponse object:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.contentencoding%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Values include:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

  - System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
  - System.Text.UnicodeEncoding
  - System.Text.UTF7Encoding
  - System.Text.UTF8Encoding

PS:

This really isn't "Metro" per se - just C#/.Net (albeit .Net 4.x)

Comment: I was going to answer this post. After I read this response there is no point. I was just going to suggest to convert the encoding from UTF8 to the desired encoding once he had the string.  At first made the suggestion of "write your own method" since I assumed he did his research.  Silly Silly Me.

Comment: Have you noticed that my question is for WinRT? There is no Encoding property on the HttpResponseMessage.